# How can I get data from a dataframe based on matching criteria with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list called 'common_numbers'. This list has numbers (in str format) that will match with some of the numbers in a data frame that are in the 4th column. So for example:

```
common_numbers = ['512', '653', '950']
(example row in a data frame) df = expeditious, tree, www.stackflow.com, 512, asn
```

```
data frame example:
0 0,1,2,3,4
1 host,ip,FQDN,asn,asnOrgName
2 barracuda,208.92.204.42,barracuda.godsgarden.com,17359,exampleorgName 

The commonality in common_numbers and the data frame in this example is 512. Thus, the value I want to retrieve is www.stackflow.com from the data frame.

I tried:
```

wanted_data =[]
        if i in common_values:
            print("Match found.. generating fqdn..")
            for i in df_is_not:
                wanted_data.append(df.loc[df[2].isin(common_values)])
            print(wanted_fqdn_data)

```
It returns:
Columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
Index: [], Empty DataFrame
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this? Thanks so much. With the example I gave above I'm expecting to get:

```
print(wanted_data)
>>>['www.stackflow.com']
```

Comment: Kindly show us the frame so that we can see what exactly you mean

Comment: Is this what you want:
`Liste=frame.col4.tolist()
list(set(Liste)-set(Common_numbers))`
This will give you the items which are in the frame but not in the common list

Comment: @SMS I added an example from the data frame. Looking to try your solution. Will keep you posted.

Comment: @SMS after trying that's close. I'm looking for the items that are in the frame (in the column over) AND in the common list. Going to try to tweak your solution for it.

Comment: neither the list of common_numbers not the dataframe has `'www.stackflow.com'` , can you edit the dataframe with a proper example which suits the question

Comment: @anky_91 the list common_numbers and the data frame have '512' in common. Since the 512 is common between them I want 'www.stackflow.com' to be returned from the data frame.

Comment: Then do this `list(set(Liste) & set(Common_numbers))`, which gives the intersection of two lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(['512', '653', '950'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['expeditious', 'tree', 'www.stackflow.com', '512', 'asn'], 
                  ['barracuda','208.92.204.42','barracuda.godsgarden.com','17359','exampleorgName']], 
                   columns=['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5'])
df3 = df2.merge(df1, left_on=['c4'], right_on=[0], how='inner', left_index=False)[['c3']]

df3
```

The result will be

```
c3
0   www.stackflow.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, there just really isn't a need for a loop in this case.

If you ultimately just want to pull out the third column of every row where the fourth column is in a list you have, then you can do the following:

```
df = df[df[3].isin(common_numbers)]
wanted_data = list(df[2])
```

Hopefully, this answers your question.

Comment: Hi Quinn, that looks close to it but not exactly right. I have 4 values in common_numbers. Thus I should only get 4 values returned to me but this returns all of the values in the column.

Comment: Does your data frame have multiple rows where the fourth column has a value that is in the common_numbers list? If so, do you just want to get the first occurrence of each?

Comment: If that is the case, then you just want to drop_duplicates based off of that column before filtering on it. So just edit to: `df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=3)

df = df[df[3].isin(common_numbers)]

wanted_data = list(df[2])` If that doesn't solve it then sorry I must be misunderstanding the question.